# jQuery functions conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

Task:

- If the radio button is selected - show the hidden image and text, do not hide until you switch to another radio button.
- Hover to the text of the radio button - show only the picture and hide after mouse leave

With my code, only the second function of the hover works. When you hover the radio button, the picture appears, but when you select it, it just disappears.

Separate functions work fine.

How can I fix it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.img2, .img3, .img4, .img5, .img6, .img7').hide();
    $('#pic1').css('opacity', '1');
    $('.text').hide();


    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'item1') {
            $('#pic5, #text1').show();
        }

        else {
            $('#pic5, #text1').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'item2') {
            $('#pic3, #text2').show();
            $('#pic1').css('opacity', '0.4');
        }
        else {
            $('#pic3, #text2').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'item3') {
            $('#pic7, #text3').show();
            $('#pic7').css('opacity', '0.4');
        }
        else {
            $('#pic7, #text3').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'item4') {
            $('#pic4, #text4').show();
            $('#pic1').css('opacity', '0.4');
        }
        else {
            $('#pic4, #text4').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'item5') {
            $('#pic5, #text5').show();
            $('#pic1').css('opacity', '0.4');
        }
        else {
            $('#text5').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'item6') {
            $('#pic6, #text6').show();
            $('#pic1').css('opacity', '0.4');
        }
        else {
            $('#text6').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'item7') {
            $('#pic7, #text7').show();
            $('#pic1').css('opacity', '0.4');
        }
        else {
            $('#text7').hide();
        }

    });

    $("#desc1").mouseenter(function() {
        $('#pic5').show();
    });
    $("#desc1").mouseleave(function() {
        $('#pic5').hide();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <div class="image">
      <div class="img1" id="pic1"><img src="img/main_v3-38.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="img2" id="pic2"><img src="img/main_v3-41.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="img3" id="pic3"><img src="img/main_v3-44.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="img4" id="pic4"><img src="img/main_v3-47.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="img5" id="pic5"><img src="img/main_v3-50.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="img6" id="pic6"><img src="img/main_v3-53.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="img7" id="pic7"><img src="img/main_v3-56.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <form class="radiobuttons">
      <p id="desc1"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item1" value="1">Варианты монтажа</p>
      <p id="desc2"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item2" value="1">Роллетные профили</p>
      <p id="desc3"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item3" value="1">Концевой профиль</p>
      <p id="desc4"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item4" value="1">Направляющие шины</p>
      <p id="desc5"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item5" value="1">Защитный короб</p>
      <p id="desc6"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item6" value="1">Боковые крышки, консоль</p>
      <p id="desc7"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item7" value="1">Октогональный вал</p>
      <p id="desc7"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item7" value="1">Концевой захват</p>
      <p id="desc7"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item7" value="1">Система управления</p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text" id="text1">Lorem Ipsum Text1</div>
<div class="text" id="text2">Lorem Ipsum Text2</div>
<div class="text" id="text3">Lorem Ipsum Text3</div>
<div class="text" id="text4">Lorem Ipsum Text4</div>
<div class="text" id="text5">Lorem Ipsum Text5</div>
<div class="text" id="text6">Lorem Ipsum Text6</div>
```

Comment: Could you include your html? Maybe it can be fixed with an onChange or onClick

Comment: `console.log($(this).attr('id'))` above your if statement and check it using browser console if it is having value `item1`,also please try to give a title to the question that briefs about the problem more clearly.

Comment: can you mail me the code. i can fix it and sent to you

Comment: @LahiruMadusanka This kind of misses the point of StackOverflow.. You should answer the question here since it was asked here... other people in the future can learn if the encounter the same issue.

Comment: @Sparky I've edited the post and added code.

Comment: @LahiruMadusanka I've edited the post and added code.

Comment: How it should look, Screenshot would be nice.

Comment: @techie_28 Thank you for your passion. I've edited post title. Also, I've checked id and its correct.

Comment: Open your browser console & click on radio button,the console.log statement should log the ID for you.

Comment: Please replace the image src attribute values by images that work in the snippet using an image placeholder service.

Comment: @KakuSarmah I've added screenshots to the post

Comment: do a `console.log('mouseleave')` inside `mouseleave()` & check while clicking the radio button.if it logs than the mouseleave is also being fired on click.This can be debugged using the breakpoints of browser console also.

Comment: Also This is a very bad code when you could have a single   `$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {` & have all if/else conditions in it for each case.

Comment: @techie_28 thank you for this hint, I've edited the code

Comment: I meant the design sorry, what is your output design wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, there is a conflict here, but it is working as it should based on what you have.

```
$("#desc1").mouseleave(function() {
    $('#pic5').hide();
});
```

It doesn't matter if you have clicked this button or not, when the mouse moves away it will hide the picture.
Try this

```
$("#desc1").mouseleave(function() {
    if($('#item1').prop('checked') === false) {
        $('#pic5').hide();
    }
});
```